# Does the `Cursor` contain all the rows of the query or only the first row?

Tags: android, mysql, database, android-cursor

I have been reading about the `Cursor` API in Android and also other people's comments on it. But there is something that I just haven't been able to understand.

When a query is made, does the `Cursor` contain **ALL** the rows of the query or **only the first row** the query?

If it returns all the rows then why people say that the `Cursor` **points to a single row** of the query? Because there is this need to call `moveToFirst()` to move the `Cursor` to the next row.

If it returns all the rows then how come it **knows** the number of rows in the query using the `getCount()` method?

I was trying to understand `Cursor` by comparing it to `ArrayList` for example.
In an `ArrayList` we access each record using the **index** of the list.
This **index** is actually the **pointer** that points to a single record of an `ArrayList`.

So, from what I see, it looks like the `Cursor` only has **one row** in it. As I call `moveX()` methods it will return me the next record of data. But then how does it know the number of results in the query?

Comment: it contains all the rows: you can get them directly using `moveToPosition(position)` where `position` is in range [0..`getCount()` -1]

Comment: what about people saying it **points to a single row**?

Comment: because all `Cursor#get*` methods can access only "current" row - the row that is selected by one of `Cursor#move*` method

Comment: okay...so if `Cursor` has all rows then what is the name of the object that returns **this current row**?

Comment: what is the object of the row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171851/discussion-between-imran-razak-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

A `Cursor` is an object that point to a single row by row's index. In primary case of query, `Cursor` point's to null's row of result set. Then you should move it to the first row or each row you want.

Answer (score 0):

A Cursor object is returned from a query, It will return all rows that the query returns.

It has all the rows, but points to only 1 row, which means for you to retrieve a row you need to point the cursor to it first

Comment: I think that is exactly where the problem is...the `Cursor` **is not moved**..what actually is moved is the **pointer** that the `Cursor` class has inside it..right? Because the `Cursor` is the **whole** set..

Comment: @imran.razak
Yes the `Cursor` has the whole set, but then when you say Cusror.move, you point the Cursor to a place inside itself.

Like for example I give you a Table, and then tell you LOOK in the 1st row, you still have the table, and you're the one who is looking inside it as well

Comment: yes...but **that place inside itself** is not the `Cursor`..it is the **row** and that row is not a `Cursor` object..its just a row..

Comment: @imran.razak 
The android docs is saying:

" moveToFirst()
Move the cursor to the first row."

Yes the row isn't a `Cursor` but the `Cursor` *points* to this *row*